# Duration of Video in Express.js: NaN

Tags: javascript, html, video, express, pug

I am trying to get the total duration of a video, in Express.js. Below I have shown my Code in Jade. Initially I include the video in the webpage.

```
video(width='320', height='240', controls='controls')
       source(src='/images/video.mp4', type='video/ogg', id='theVideo')
```

Then I call the folowing function on a button click.

```
function getCurrentTime() {
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    var time = video.duration;
    document.getElementById('myTime').value=time;
   }
```

'myTime' is just a text box.

```
input(id='myTime', size='5')
```

But when I run the video, I get as the duration NaN. I tried to read some posts on why this happens, and apparently it is related to a "byte" problem, or sending headers or something like that. Can someone please explain to me the reason why it is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Jade:

```
video(width='320', height='240', controls='controls', id='theVideo')
   source(src='/images/video.mp4', type='video/ogg')
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
     var video = document.getElementById('theVideo');
     video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
         console.log(Math.round(video.duration));
     });
});
```

Comment: It does not print anything to the terminal.

Comment: The problem was because I was declaring 'theVideo' in source not in video. Thanks :D